# Transferring some parts of image

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to transfer some part of my image to another matrix with this code:

```
p1 = zeros(512,512,3);
p1(1:128, 1:128, 1:3) = image(1:128, 129:256, 1:3);
```

And when this code did not work I tried with 3 for loop
and after that I tried to transfer **R G B** layers separately:

```
p1(1:128, 1:128, 1) = image(1:128, 129:256, 1);
```

But none of these codes work. Could anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Are you sure `image` has at least 256 columns and at least 128 rows? what do you mean by "not work" - can you post the exact error message you get?

Comment: my image size is 512,512,3

Comment: what is the exact error you get?

Comment: just to be sure - `image ` can also refer to a builtin command. Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Matlab* you can always assign one matrix to another with the same size. For example:

```
A = ones (4,2,3,4,5);
B = zeros(4,2,3,4,5);
A = B
```

will run with no errors.

It is possible that the type of the image you are using is **uint8** (*8-bit unsigned integer*), while `zeros` creates a *double* matrix. This will result in improper behavior of operations or built-in functions, if you do not **cast** (change the type of) your matrices properly. Use [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) to check the type of your image:

```
whos image
```

Try to cast the `zeros` to **uint8**:

```
p1 = uint8(zeros(512,512,3));
...
```

Here is an example:

```
image = imread('peppers.png');
partail_im = uint8(zeros(size(image)));
partail_im(1:128,1:128,:) = image(1:128,129:256,:);
imshow(partail_im);
```

Note: It's better not to use image as the name of any variable since it's name of a built-in function [**`image`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html).

Comment: My image size is 512,512,3 and i do not have error mg. but there is no part of image in matrix p1 .Actually i want to make a new image with parts of original image.

Comment: As I said, I think you are trying `imshow` or another function to view `p1` and since `p1` is a *bad scaled double matrix* you probably see a black image or something you don't expect.

Comment: Thank you.my code with using unit8 working perfectly.but i should always use unit8 when i using imshow and transferring image ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of image you are working with, I'm no expert but I have heard of two kinds of intensities: double from 0 to 1 and integer from 0 to 255. You can check this with `whos` command to see the type: `whos image`. If you want to store the intensity of the second type (**uint8**) you should always use **uint8** matrices. Also try not to use `image` as the name of your iamge since it's a name of a function as @bdecaf mentioned.